# How to Test React's Error Boundary using Jest and React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

How do I write a unit test in Jest / React Testing Library to test if React's Error Boundary, using the npm library `react-error-boundary`, is working correctly? E.g.

```
const ErrorFallback = ({error}) => <p>There was an error!</p>     // can use error.message later

const SimpleComponent = () => <h1>Hello, world</h1>

const TopLevelComponent = () => (
  <ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={ErrorFallback}>
    <SimpleComponent />
  </ErrorBoundary>
)
```

So now my test might be:

```
describe("Error Boundary", () => {
  test("renders a fallback UI if an error occurs in a child component", () => {
    const error = throw new Error("An error occurred")

    render(<TopLevelComponent>)

    // Somehow throw an error inside of SimpleComponent
    SimpleComponent.simulateError()

    expect(screen.getByText("There was an error!")).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

So how would I accomplish this? Or have I gone in the wrong direction?

Comment: so are you going to test 3rd party lib `react-error-boundary`? if yes, there is little profit doing that since package's authors have already done that

Comment: @skyboyer I think that's an oversimplification. I haven't checked the package but even if they are doing tests they may not test your context. Writing tests for your use case is very much a good thing and we have caught a lot of upstream issues that way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that makes sense to test 3rd party component library, but you always can make a dumb component that always throws:

```
    const ComponentThatThrows = () => { throw new Error(''); };
    render(<ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={ErrorFallback}>
      <ComponentThatThrows />
    </ErrorBoundary>)

    expect(screen.getByText("There was an error!")).toBeInTheDocument()
```

If I misunderstood and you want to test specifically `TopLevelComponent` rather than `ErrorBoundary`, you need to figure out in what condition it must throw and reproduce that condition(e.g. "click initiates fetch() and there is a rejection" or alike).

Simulating error back then in Enzyme([`.simulateError()`](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/simulateError.html)) was convenient but the same way fragile as direct call to `wrapper.setState()` - our tests still might pass but in real code it could be just impossible to reach that case.